# SQL query to get free vehicles on basis of their booking date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, inventory-management

Here is my Inventory Table,

[image: Inventory Table]

And this one is my Engaged Inventory Log Table,

[image: EngagedInventoryLog]

and there is also a Main Booking Table with different fields with detailed information of a particular booking.

Once a row created in Main Booking Table , trigger for insertion is there to insert in the `EngagedInventoryLog` Table with their respective `PickupDate`, `DropDate`and the `RegistrationNo` of the Vehicle Booked from the Main Booking Table.

Now , If am going to do a booking with PickupDate = 15/09/2019 10:00:00 
and DropDate = 16/09/2019 16:00:00 then only those vehicles should be available which are free or not booked or in other words not clash with the Records in `EngagedInventoryLog`, `PickupDate` and `DropDate` Column. (i.e RegisNo 2345)

Similarly in case of: 10/09/2019 10:00:00 to 13/09/2019 10:00:00 we have to get both vehicles with RegisNo i.e 1234 , 2345

In Case of 10/09/2019 10:00:00 to 17/09/2019 10:00:00 No Vehicles should be there.

And Here is the query which i have tried but it doesn't works on some cases,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, VehicleName + '#' + ISNULL(RegisNo, '') AS 'Model'
FROM            Inventory
WHERE SupplierName = 'John'
AND
RegisNo NOT IN (
SELECT RegisNo FROM EngagedInventoryLog
WHERE
CONVERT(DATETIME,'15/09/2019 10:00:00',103) <  DropDate
    AND convert(DATETIME,'16/09/2019 16:00:00',103) > PickupDate
```

)

Comment: Please, **do not** post sample data as images, instead post DDL DML or post them as _formatted text_ Or even more better [create a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Why `PickupDate` column doesn't have dates in the first image?

Comment: Do you not know when the `date`, `'Honda City'` is @Sami?

Comment: @Larnu  Honda City is booked for 16/09/2019 to 21/09/2019.

Comment: @Larnu Nope, I suppose it's a date there from the col name, I dunno what's `'Honda City'` is. Seems like it's a car not a date as was posted before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXITS` condition to pull out the vehicules for which no engagement exists that overlaps the target range:

```
SELECT *
FROM Inventory i
WHERE 
    SupplierName = 'John'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM EngagedInventory e
        WHERE 
            e.RegisNo = i.RegisNo
            AND @PickupDate <= e.DropDate 
            AND @DropDate >= e.PickupDate
    )
```

You can replace `@PickupDate` and `@DropDate` with the date range for which you want to create the new engagement.

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c927a2a06128d87d1e3b04139ea6de9)** with your sample data, when given pickup date `'2019-09-15 10:00:00'` and drop date `'2019-09-16 10:00:00'`, the query returns:

```
id | SupplierName | VehiculeName | RegisNo
-: | :----------- | :----------- | ------:
 2 | John         | Creta        |    2345
```

Comment: It doesn't work for date 13/09/2019 to 15/09/2019 , as in this case 1234 should be eliminated.

Comment: @HamzaKhan: this seems to work as expected. I added a DB Fiddle link to my answer for you to check (side note: next time, pls post your data as tabular text instead of images...).